# Как создать свойство для параметров конструктора класса? C#

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, конструктор

Класс и конструктор, и метод:

```
class Worker
{
    public Worker(double p)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public double p;
    private double k = 1.2;

    public void Count()
    {
        double salary = p * k;
        Console.WriteLine($"Зарплата {lastname} составляет {salary}");
    }
}
```

Свойство (не работает):

```
public double P
{
    get { return p; }
    set { if (p > 0) { p = value; } else { Console.WriteLine("Зарплата не может быть отрицательной"); } }
}
```

Создание объекта:

```
Worker John = new Worker (-1000);
```

Как запретить передавать отрицательные числа при создании объекта?

Comment: `if (p > 0)` -> `if (value > 0)`. `p` - это старое значение свойства, а `value` текущее заданное. И да, отвыкайте от названий в виде `P`, даже для тестирования...

Comment: `if (p > 0)` это условие никогда не выполнится, потому что `p` изначально `0`, и свойства тут не при чем, этот код в любом месте бы не работал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private double p;

public Worker(double p)
{
  P = p;
  ^
}
```

плюс то, что в комментарии:

```
public double P
{
  get { return p; }
  set { 
    if (value <= 0)
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("Зарплата должна быть положительной."); 
    p = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Свою ошибку понял: значение надо присваивать через свойство.

Comment: Сообщение о зарплате появляется. Но всё равно счёт в методе производится с нулем. Как сделать так, чтобы при отрицательном p счёт не вёлся? Неужели условие ставить в в методе? Звучит неплохо.

Comment: @Максим Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Answer (score 1):

Должно работать:

```
public double P
{
    get { return p; }
    set { if (value > 0) { p = value; } else { Console.WriteLine("Зарплата не может быть отрицательной"); } }
}
```

У вас не работало, потому что вы дёргали старое значение, а не значение которое передаётся

---

Или же можно вот так

```
public Worker(double p)
    {
        if(p>0)
        {
            this.p = p;
        }
    }
```